# Get the file extension of the file chosen by OpenFileDialog

Tags: vb.net, openfiledialog, recover

I am using an `OpenFileDialog` to allow the user to select a file.  How do I then get the extension of the file that they chose?  I need to perform a different action depending on the type of file.  For instance, if they choose a PDF file, I need to launch a PDF viewer, but if it's am image, I need to show it in a `PictureBox`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Path.GetExtension`:

```
Select Case Path.GetExtension(myDialog.FileName).ToLower()
    Case ".pdf"
        ' ...
End Select
```

Comment: The `.` period is included in the extension, I've added it in.

Answer (score 4):

You also could use `Extension` as blew:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module DialogExtensions
    <Extension()>
    Public Function GetFileExtention(ByVal dialog As OpenFileDialog) As String
        Return Path.GetExtension(dialog.FileName)
    End Function
End Module
```

And simply use this extension as blow:

```
If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
     Dim s As String = OpenFileDialog1.GetFileExtention()
End If
```

Comment: GetFileExtention() is not a type of openfiledialog1 
but thanks for your help

Comment: @Zied.M you must add Module DialogExtensions to you project, are you add that Module to your project?

Comment: Must adding module , I did and worked for me thanks .